# The $v$-operation on a ring $R$ is not of finite type

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $v$ be the $v$-operation on $R$. It is obvious that if $R$ is a noetherien domain, then $v$ is of finite type.

What is the easiest example of a domain $R$ such that the $v$-operation is not of finite type ?

I read somewhere that if $R$ is a non noetherien valuation ring of Krull dimension 1 then the $v$-operation on $R$ is not of finite type, but I can't see why.

Comment: What is $v$-operation and what do you mean by it being finite type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's run through the reasoning that the $v$-operation for a $1$-dimensional non-Noetherian valuation domain is not finite type.

**Exercise 1**: For every $*$-operation of finite type, the set of $*$-maximal ideals is non-empty.  Moreover every $*$-maximal ideal is prime.

By $*$-maximal we mean maximal among the set of $*$-ideals.  This fact is proved via Zorn's lemma much like the special case $*$ = identity (aka $d$-operation).

**Exercise 2** A divisorial ideal of a valuation domain is precisely the intersection of the principal ideals containing it.

**Exercise 3** Every non-maximal prime of a valuation domain is divisorial.

Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ together, we get that **a valuation domain has a $v$-maximal ideal iff its maximal ideal is principal**.  If the $v$-operation is finite type, then $(1)$ tells us that this must be the case.  If moreover $V$ is $1$-dimensional, this forces it to be a DVR.

Comment: I highly recommend going through Gabelli's short course notes for a succinct introduction to $*$-operations.  
http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/users/gabelli/dispense/IdealNotes2.pdf

Comment: But you should try to prove all of these exercises for yourself!